# Javascript Breakpoint When 'undefined' is used

Tags: google-chrome, browser, undefined, javascript-debugger

I am asking about Google Chrome Debugging, but it could be a question about any browser that does this in their debugging.

I have a piece of javascript that runs several times a second for a number of seconds. It does a load of calculations. These calculations are done on floating point variables, BUT I suspect after several seconds an `undefined` number is accidently stumbled upon.

I do not know when it happens and cannot predict it myself. So I need the debugger to pause and let me inspect the code when some maths is done involving an `undefined` number.

I want to rule out loads of editing within the code. I do not want to put in a load of `debugger;` lines in conditional statements. I am looking for a way for the browser to spot I am using an undefined and pause the debugging console.

**How can I get Google Chrome (or any other browser with a decent debugging mode) pause when it reaches a calculation that involves an `undefined` number?**

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `undefined` and use the `debugger;` keyword.

Within your code

```
...
if (xyz === undefined) {
  debugger;
}
...
```

For more details, see here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#debugger

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have edited the question to rule out large rewrites of the code itself. I am looking for something that will pause a debugger without the need for altering the code with a load of `debugger` statements.